# Clojure: How do I access SQLException from a clojure/leiningen project?

Tags: sql, exception, clojure

I have a sql exception from clojure that goes like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: transaction rolled back: 
  Batch entry 0 drop database triface was aborted.  
Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

I want to call getNextException on the exception I receive:

```
(require [clojure.contrib.sql :as sql])

(try 
  (db/rebuild-table) ;; function causing the exception
  (catch Exception e (.getNextException e)))
```

But then I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: 
  getNextException for class java.lang.Exception
```

So I assume I want to catch a SQLException:

```
(catch SQLException e (.getNextException e)))
```

Except I can't find how to require this class.  It does not seem to be provided by either clojure.contrib.sql or clojure.contrib.sql.internal.  The javadocs say it is in java.sql, but how do I require that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't require it, you import it,

```
(import java.sql.SQLException)
```

but even if you catch a Exception as long as it is a SQLException you should be able to call getNextException

```
(let [up (SQLException. "throw")]
  (try
    (throw up)
    (catch Exception e (isa? (type e) SQLException))))
```

Comment: Hmm... you are correct.  It seems the problem is that the exception is a java.lang.Exception, even though it is asking me to call .getNextException on it?  Has the exception been downcast?

Comment: Alright, turns out I needed to call .getCause first, THEN .getNextException.  Thanks for the import tip!

Comment: Why not catch `SQLException` instead of checking type with `isa?`